# Regex to extract lines that starts with any character but not with characters /words like Rs or SBC using Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Below is the input file:

```
8% OFF
Sugar Free Gold Sweetener
500 tablets
Rs230
Rs 250
SBC IconClub Price: Rs227
43% OFF
Palm Oil (Bottle)
1 l
Rs186
Rs 330
SBC IconClub Price: Rs185
```

I am trying to extract those lines that are not starting with either Rs or SBC or any number. They are actually product names which are starting with words only. I used below Regex:

```
^[A-Za-z].*$
```

This removed the lines starting with numbers only.
However, I am unable to remove the below lines that are starting with RS, and SBC.

```
Rs230
Rs 250
SBC IconClub Price: Rs227
Rs186
Rs 330
SBC IconClub Price: Rs185
```

Could anyone please help me with the regex in Python which can give the product name only? Products are on line 2 and 8.

Comment: You can use `^(?!SBC|R[sS])[A-Za-z].*$`

Comment: Thanks a lot @The fourth bird. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude matching `SBC` `RS` or `Rs` using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!SBC|R[sS])[A-Za-z].*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2GKXSe/1)

If the strings all start with an uppercase char, you can also use

```
^(?!SBC|R[sS])[A-Z].*$
```